# forgerock AM 7.1 with embedded DS setup fails

Tags: installation, configuration, openldap, openam, forgerock

I am completely new to openam. Facing issue with am7.1 setup. Followed steps from this doc for installation, https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/7.1/eval-guide/

**issue**: After login to openam, It fails with 'Create Default configuration'.

10/29/2021 07:19:24:042 AM UTC: Loading Schema opendj_user_schema.ldif 10/29/2021 07:19:24:053 AM UTC: ...Failed. AMSetupDSConfig.loadSchemaFiles:failedConnect Error: No operational connection factories available at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapException.newLdapException(LdapException.java:230)

**Setup Details:**

1. Ubuntu OS 18.04 LTS
2. $ java -version
   Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m
   openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)
3. apache tomcat 8.5.72
4. updated tomcat/bin/setenv.sh with
   export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
   export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

5.using root having correct permissions on $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts

After login to openam, It fails with 'Create Default configuration'

10/29/2021 07:18:59:484 AM UTC: License terms accepted.
License, legal-notices/Forgerock_License.txt, has been accepted.
License Hash: Yalwb9SLaQCqu0NjseRm+vqup41ucHzs83eS3VP3uZI=.
10/29/2021 07:18:59:493 AM UTC: Checking configuration directory /home/midadev1/am.
10/29/2021 07:19:03:473 AM UTC: ...Success.
10/29/2021 07:19:05:619 AM UTC: Extracting DS, please wait...
10/29/2021 07:19:11:897 AM UTC: Complete
10/29/2021 07:19:11:897 AM UTC: Running DS setup
10/29/2021 07:19:15:330 AM UTC: ...Success
10/29/2021 07:19:15:332 AM UTC: Starting DS for serverRoot /home/midadev1/am/opends
10/29/2021 07:19:21:392 AM UTC: ...Success.
10/29/2021 07:19:21:392 AM UTC: ...Success.
10/29/2021 07:19:21:393 AM UTC: Installing embedded DS configuration store in /home/midadev1/am/opends
10/29/2021 07:19:21:527 AM UTC: Creating AM suffix
10/29/2021 07:19:23:641 AM UTC: ...Success
10/29/2021 07:19:23:715 AM UTC: Tag swapping schema files.
10/29/2021 07:19:23:754 AM UTC: ...Success.
10/29/2021 07:19:23:755 AM UTC: Loading Schema opendj_config_schema.ldif
10/29/2021 07:19:24:042 AM UTC: ...Success.
**10/29/2021 07:19:24:042 AM UTC: Loading Schema opendj_user_schema.ldif
10/29/2021 07:19:24:053 AM UTC: ...Failed.
AMSetupDSConfig.loadSchemaFiles:failedConnect Error: No operational connection factories availabl**e
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapException.newLdapException(LdapException.java:230)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapException.newLdapException(LdapException.java:145)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapException.newLdapException(LdapException.java:114)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapException.newLdapException(LdapException.java:72)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LoadBalancer.noOperationalConnectionFactoriesException(LoadBalancer.java:768)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LoadBalancer.connect0(LoadBalancer.java:326)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleFromCallable.subscribeActual(SingleFromCallable.java:43)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual(SingleMap.java:35)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn.subscribeActual(SingleObserveOn.java:35)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.single.SingleDoFinally.subscribeActual(SingleDoFinally.java:44)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813)
at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4799)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapConnectionFactory.getConnectionAsync(LdapConnectionFactory.java:346)
at org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LdapConnectionFactory.getConnection(LdapConnectionFactory.java:353)
at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupDSConfig.loadSchemaFiles(AMSetupDSConfig.java:258)
at com.sun.identity.setup.AMSetupServlet.writeSchemaFiles(AMSetupServlet.java:1514)

any advice please.

Comment: Please note that embedded configuration data store is not supported in production environments, hence you should not even use it in lower stages environment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by an issue of the underlying embedded Directory Service (DS), complaining about missing disk space.

```
[13/Juli/2022:09:21:50 +0200] category=CORE severity=ERROR msgID=139 msg=The Directory Server has sent an alert notification generated by class org.opends.server.extensions.DiskSpaceMonitor (alert type org.opends.server.DiskFull, alert ID org.opends.messages.core-750): The free space (869,01 megabytes) on the disk containing directory "C:\" is below full threshold for the following subsystems: "appData Backend" (low=10,34 gigabytes, full=6,34 gigabytes). Write operations to the backend, replication updates included, will fail until the free space rises above the threshold
```

DS requirements are significant and mentioned in the Evaluation Guide as well https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/am/7.1/eval-guide/step-1-prepare-server.html

> The DS server requires free disk space equal to or greater than 5 GB, plus 5% of the total size of the filesystem in the $HOME directory of the user running the container.